# Openfire: how to add and autorenew a letsencrypt certificate?

Tags: openfire

How to add letsencrypt certificate auto-generated by [certbot like](https://certbot.eff.org/lets-encrypt/centos6-apache.html) this to open fire

1. Letsencrypt certificates have no passwords, if it does I don't know it  since it's auto-generated but I'm certain that it doesn't have a password
2. I have a cron that auto-renew it, therefore I want to auto-renew it on Openfire as well

If I use the certificate manager, someone would have to renew it by hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the readme from the Certificate Manager Plugin:

Certificate Manager Plugin Readme
Overview

The Certificate Manager plugin adds functionality to Openfire that relates to administration of its certificate stores.
Installation

Copy certificatemanager.jar into the plugins directory of your Openfire installation. The plugin will then be automatically deployed. To upgrade to a new version, copy the new certificatemanager.jar file over the existing file.
Configuration

The plugin is configured via the Openfire Admin Console. After installation, a new Admin Console page is available. The page can be found under in the "Server", "TLS/SSL Certificates" tab. There, this plugin adds a new item on the side-bar, named "Management".
Using the Plugin

**This plugin allows Openfire to monitor file changes in a particular directory (which, by default, is /resources/security/hotdeploy/). Whenever a set of files is found that consists of a PEM-encoded private key and a PEM-encoded certificate chain, this plugin will attempt to install them in the Openfire identity store.**
Let's Encrypt / Certbot integration

The directory watcher mechanism, described above, is an excellent way to make use of the periodically updated data that's generated by Let's Encrypts Certbot. Openfire can be configured to monitor the directory in which certbot places renewed data. This can, however, lead to file-permission issues (the certbot directories are often not readable by the Openfire process). An alternative solution is to use certbots post-hook to copy the data into a directory that can be used by Openfire.

Answer (score 5):

To expand on Bo Kersey helpful answer, to complete the final part of his answer: "use certbots post-hook to copy the data into a directory that can be used by Openfire". These are the steps to complete this part of the answer:

The[Certbot renew with post-hook documentation](https://certbot.eff.org/docs/using.html?highlight=hook#re-creating-and-updating-existing-certificates), indicates that script can be run from: `/etc/letsencrypt/renewal-hooks/post` to achieve a solution:

> "You can also specify hooks by placing files in subdirectories of
>   Certbot’s configuration directory. Assuming your configuration
>   directory is `/etc/letsencrypt`, any executable files found in
>   `/etc/letsencrypt/renewal-hooks/pre`,
>   `/etc/letsencrypt/renewal-hooks/deploy`, and
>   `/etc/letsencrypt/renewal-hooks/post` will be run as pre, deploy, and
>   post hooks respectively when any certificate is renewed with the renew
>   subcommand."

**Solution Steps...**

This solution relies on the OpenFire Certificate Manager plug-in - as indicated above. To install the plug-in, download the plug-in file: certificatemanager.jar from the OpenFire plug-ins page, at the following link: https://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/plugins.jsp

Then, in the OpenFire consul, on the Plug-in tab, select, and then upload, the certificatemanager.jar file. This should install the plug-in - see screenshot below.

[image]

A new tab should appear in the OpenFire Consul: Server > TLS/SSL Certificates. This indicates that the plug-in is installed correctly.

With the plug-in installed, go back to the terminal and run the following commands:

```
sudo su
cd /etc/letsencrypt/renewal-hooks/post
nano copykeys.sh
```

Copy and paste:

```
#!/bin/bash
cp /etc/letsencrypt/live/MY-DOMAIN/privkey.pem /resources/security/hotdeploy/my-domain-privkey.pem
cp /etc/letsencrypt/live/MY-DOMAIN/fullchain.pem /resources/security/hotdeploy/my-domain-fullchain.pem
```

Save and exit:

`Ctrl` and then `X`, then `Y`, then `Enter`

The make script executable:

```
chmod +x copykeys.sh
```

Done!

Comment: I had to add the following command on the copykeys.sh so that the keys are own by openfire: chown openfire:openfire /resources/security/hotdeploy/my-domain-privkey.pem; chown openfire:openfire /resources/security/hotdeploy/my-domain-fullchain.pem

Comment: In my case, the path was actually `/usr/share/openfire/resources/security/hotdeploy/...`, that is, with `/ust/share/openfire/` added